# Angular 5 save/load pdf with base64

Tags: angular, pdf

I'm using angular 5 and trying to save/load pdf files.

1.) I save the entire raw base64 string. It looks like the fileBase64 var below. Is that ok?

2.) Then when trying to load the pdf I do the below code. My question is what goes in the Blob() array? I was putting the entire base64 string, but that does not work? help!

I have the following ts code in my controller:

```
downloadPDF(file: any) {

     var fileBase64 = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAg";

     var tab = window.open();
     var data = new Blob([fileBase64], { type: 'application/pdf', });
     var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);
     tab.location.href = fileUrl;     
}
```